# Where can I find this appengine screen?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using google appengine and I want to find this screen.  I have looked in the google console and the api-explorer pages but I can't seem to find it.  I know that it exists and I need to configure my application.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is part of application called Mobile Backend Starter.

You can easy deploy it from `https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~PROJECT_NAME/mobilesample`
Replace PROJECT_NAME with your project.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't see the screen that Im looking for, Im trying to alter the authentication / authorization settings for the app and I don't see that screen on that page.  I do see the console.developers page but I don't know how to change these settings... can you point me to the page?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/authentication -- description of settings you're looking for.

Comment: The Mobile Backend Starter is no longer available, just in case someone in the future is looking for it.